# How to correctly implement a Neuraxle pipeline step that filters data_inputs?

Tags: python, pipeline, neuraxle

I am trying to implement a `BaseStep` in neuraxle (0.5.2) that filters `data_input` (and `expected_output` accordingly).

```
class DataFrameQuery(NonFittableMixin, InputAndOutputTransformerMixin, BaseStep):
    def __init__(self, query):
        super().__init__()
        self.query = query
    
    def transform(self, data_input):
        data_input, expected_output = data_input
        # verify that input and output are either pd.DataFrame or pd.Series
        # ... [redacted] ...
        new_data_input = data_input.query(self.query)
        if all(output is None for output in expected_output):
            new_expected_output = [None] * len(new_data_input)
        else:
            new_expected_output = expected_output.loc[new_data_input.index]
        return new_data_input, new_expected_output
```

This naturally (in most cases) will lead to a change in `len(data_inputs)` (and `expected_outputs`). In the recent version of `neuraxle`, I am getting an `AssertionError`:

```
data_input = pd.DataFrame([{"A": 1, "B": 1}, {"A": 2, "B": 2}], index=[1, 2])
expected_output = pd.Series([1, 2], index=[1, 2])
pipeline = Pipeline([
    DataFrameQuery("A == 1")
])
pipeline.fit_transform(data_input, expected_output)
```

```
AssertionError: InputAndOutputTransformerMixin: 
    Caching broken because there is a different len of current ids, and data inputs. 
    Please use InputAndOutputTransformerWrapper if you plan to change the len of the data inputs.
```

From my understanding, this is where Neuraxle's [Handler Methods](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/handler_methods.html) should come into play. However, so far I have not found one to use which enables me to update the `current_id`s for the inputs and outputs after the transformation  (I guess it should be `_did_transform`, but that doesn't appear to get called).

Generally:

- What is the correct way to update `current_ids` for both inputs and expected outputs after a transformation (in the same step)?
- What are the aspects to watch out for when applying side-effects on the `data_container`? Are the identifiers e.g. used to split data for SIMD-parallelism? Are the new identifiers generally expected to be a sequence of integers?

Edit: I have also tried setting the `savers` and using the `InputAndOutputTransformerWrapper` as described [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Fcf1eOPW2vEJ:https://gitmemory.com/alexbrillant+&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=firefox-b-e). Still getting the following error (might be because I am not sure where to call the `handle_transform`):

```
AssertionError: InputAndOutputTransformerWrapper: 
    Caching broken because there is a different len of current ids, and data inputs.
    Please resample the current ids using handler methods, or create new ones by setting the wrapped step saver to HashlibMd5ValueHasher using the BaseStep.set_savers method.
```

Edit: For now I have solved the problem as follows:

```
class OutputShapeChangingStep(NonFittableMixin, InputAndOutputTransformerMixin, BaseStep):
    def __init__(self, idx):
        super().__init__()
        self.idx = idx
        
    def _update_data_container_shape(self, data_container):
        assert len(data_container.expected_outputs) == len(data_container.data_inputs)
        data_container.set_current_ids(range(len(data_container.data_inputs)))
        data_container = self.hash_data_container(data_container)
        return data_container
    
    def _set_data_inputs_and_expected_outputs(self, data_container, new_inputs, new_expected_outputs) -> DataContainer:
        data_container.set_data_inputs(new_inputs)
        data_container.set_expected_outputs(new_expected_outputs)
        data_container = self._update_data_container_shape(data_container)
        return data_container
    
    def transform(self, data_inputs):
        data_inputs, expected_outputs = data_inputs
        return data_inputs[self.idx], expected_outputs[self.idx]
```

I am likely "wrongly" overriding the `_set_data_inputs_and_expected_outputs` of `InputAndOutputTransformerMixin` in this case (would `_transform_data_container` be the better choice?), but like this updating the `current_ids` (and rehashing the container) appears possible. However, I'd still be interested in how to do this more in-line with Neuraxle's API expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, my favorite way to do it is to only use handler methods. It is much cleaner in my opinion.

Usage example with handler methods :

```
class WindowTimeSeries(ForceHandleMixin, BaseTransformer):
   def __init__(self):
      BaseTransformer.__init__(self)
      ForceHandleMixin.__init__(self)

   def _transform_data_container(self, data_container: DataContainer, context: ExecutionContext) -> DataContainer:
      di = data_container.data_inputs
      new_di, new_eo = np.array_split(np.array(di), 2)

      return DataContainer(
        summary_id=data_container.summary_id,
        data_inputs=new_di,
        expected_outputs=new_eo
      )
```

This way, the current ids will get recreated, and hashed with the default behavior. Note: the summary id is the most important thing. It is created at the beginning, and it is rehashed with hyperparams... If needed, you could also generate new current ids with a custom saver like the  HashlibMd5ValueHasher.

Edit, there was indeed a bug. This is fixed here : https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/pull/379

Usage example :

```
step = InputAndOutputTransformerWrapper(WindowTimeSeriesForOutputTransformerWrapper()) \
    .set_hashers([HashlibMd5ValueHasher()])
step = StepThatInheritsFromInputAndOutputTransformerMixin() \
     .set_hashers([HashlibMd5ValueHasher()])
```